# How to load different html files for jit and aot in Angular?

Tags: angular, jit, browser-sync, angular2-aot

I would like to have both just-in-time and the ahead-of-time compiler options in the same package (directory). I have different versions of: app.module.ts, main.ts, tsconfig.json and main.html files in the same directory. Can anyone tell me how to tell the lite-server to use different a different html file depending on which compiler I am using?

I think the solution is to use a configure file from browser-sync, but I have no idea how to configure it.

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/tree/master/systemjs-ngc-rollup

Answer (score 0):

try to follow below link it will good understand about mainting two html file for JIT and AOT
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#run-jit